# Comparing TIMESTAMP directly vs using month and day function

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find all `first_call_resolution =2` where `response_time` is between 01 June and 17 June in my table. However, when I tried writing:

```
WHERE first_call_resolution = 2 AND (response_time BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-17')
```

It returned:

[image]

Then I tried writing the following query, while remaining all other compoenents the same:

```
WHERE first_call_resolution = 2 AND (MONTH(response_time) = 6 AND DAY(response_time) BETWEEN 01 AND 17 AND YEAR(response_time) = 2021)
```

it returned:

[image]

The second output returned more result than the first output.

I'm wondering shouldn't both query return the same result since they both specify the time period of time, which is between '2021-06-01' and '2021-06-17'?

The `survey_response_time` is stored as `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: CAST `response_time` as a DATE SQL variable type. As Phil has done in his answer after reading my comment `;-)`

Comment: @Martin indeed helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `response_time BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-17'`

It translates to `response_time BETWEEN '2021-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-06-17 00:00:00'`

---

To match your 2nd query's result, you either want to include the time component range or `cast` response_time as date

```
response_time BETWEEN '2021-06-01 00:00:00' AND  '2021-06-17 23:59:59'
```

---

```
CAST(response_time AS DATE) BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND  '2021-06-17'
```

Comment: Helped a lot, didn’t realize TIMESTAMP comparisons didn’t compare times pass midnight, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The do not specify the same time.

The first specifies all times up to the midnight on 2021-06-17 when the day begins.

The second just looks at the date, so it include all times on that date as well.

Remember the time component!